# Mathematica: how to make Z transformation of data from CSV File

Tags: list-manipulation, import, csv-format

I have a discrete Signal in my CSV File and I want to transform it in Z. I import the data with

```
 Data=Import["T:/data.csv","CSV"]
```

and I try to transform it

```
ZTranform[Data[n],n,z]
```

but I get this Error:

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim : Recursion depth of 256 exceeded >>
```

What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confused on `ZTransform`.  This expects to take an expression as a function of `n`, for example `n^2 2^(-n)`.  If you have just numbers, then you can't do this. You need to apply the formula itself. Assuming one-sided ZTransform, then simply write

```
Clear[z, n]
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
Sum[data[[n + 1]] z^(-n), {n, 0, Length[data] - 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is simply the definition. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Transform.html

Replace data above with your own data in the CVS file. Again, I used a one-sided ZTransform in this example, which is the most common one.

Comment: Hey Nasser M. Abbasi,

Comment: i have a list with 20225 Values. what im really doing is to multiply a  ZTransformed RC model with the Z Transformation of the Current on CSV file. G(z) is my RC model und C(z) is my Current also V(z)=G(z)*C(z) . so i want to Inverse the Z Transformation of V(z) to get it on the time domain also V(t)=InverseZTransform(V(z)) but  mathematica is running and i dont become any results or error.still running :-( thank you Nasser

Answer (score 2):

For data, *Mathematica* has `ListZTransform`, which was introduced in V9 in 2012.

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomReal[1, 5];
data . z^-Range[0, Length[data] - 1] (* = definition *)
ListZTransform[data, z]
(*
  0.652468 + 0.935202/z^4 + 0.566352/z^3 + 0.682813/z^2 + 0.63307/z
  0.652468 + 0.935202/z^4 + 0.566352/z^3 + 0.682813/z^2 + 0.63307/z
*)
```

[Note that the `Dot` formula is about twice as fast as `ListZTransform`, both growing linearly in time, at up to 5000 data points.  I'm not sure why.]