# Taking numerical Laplace transform of a tabulated data with Mathematica?

Tags: integral-transforms

I am relatively new to the use of Mathematica in the context of numerical evaluations, therefore I would greatly appreciate a detailed answer and would like to express my gratitude towards any help in advance. Here is my question:

I have a list of data, `{{t1,f1},{t2,f2},{t3,f3},...,{tn,fn}}`, and I want to take a Laplace transform of this data. It would also be nice to see a plot of the data after the transformation.

Comment: The discrete equivalent of the Laplace transform is the Z-Transform. This [16755](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/mathematica-how-to-make-z-transformation-of-data-from-csv-file/16755#16755) answer shows how you can implement a Z-transform using `Sum` on discrete data. This assumes uniform sampling of your data. As far as plotting it, just use 'ListPlot[transformedData]`.

Comment: Could I also suggest that you may wish to take the Fourier transform? Some details are given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558). Taking the Laplace transform involves integrating your function when multiplied by Exp[-s t] where s may take any complex value. This means that you  have a two parameter plot of the transform to consider (one axis real values, another imaginary values). As NJ Evans states for sampled data the Z-Transform is more standard.

Comment: As noted, by N.J.Evans and Hugh the numerical Laplace transform is not widely used.  It is difficult to advise on your best way forward without seeing the data or knowing the application.

Comment: I am a bit late here to make suggestions but I am working on the same problem today.  My approach  to make numerical laplace transform is to take  FFTsine + FFTcos*I.  But I am not 100% of my approach here.  If equations are available then swap t to I*t before taking FFT.  For pure data, the previous suggestions are valid.